# Does a user "like" a Facebook post already

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to solve this one for a while now and have slowly realised that the call im making is not the desired call for what i want.

I am currently getting the users newsfeed and adding a like button but if they like it already it shold say unlike.

i call /me/likes?... and get a couple of bits of data (which i trawl through comparing each post id in newsfeed) but I have just realised this data is to do with pages that the user has liked. It doesn't return the posts the user has liked.

My question is how do i determine if the user has liked a post already?(my fear is that i have to make a call to the api for each post in the newsfeed to determine if the user likes this post but that would drastically slow down a mobile app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using FQL [`like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) table:

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM like 
WHERE post_id 
IN ("AAAAAA_AAAAAAAAAAA","BBBBBB_BBBBBBBBB","CCCCCCC_CCCCCCCCC") 
AND user_id = XXXXXXXXX
```

And the result will be something like:

```
[
  {
    "post_id": "CCCCCCC_CCCCCCCCC"
  }
]
```

It's always a good idea to test your queries in the [`fql.query` console](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/).

Comment: IN ("AAAAAA_AAAAAAAAAAA","BBBBBB_BBBBBBBBB","CCCCCCC_CCCCCCCCC") i dont understan this bit of the query?? Are these the post id's from the newsfeed posts?

Comment: @T-basketDotcodotuk: sure...post ids are actually strings and looks like `userid_postid`

Comment: check the example in the api [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) document to better understand

Comment: ifaour, I have succeeded, I just had to wrap the post_id's in 'post_id's' and all my likes are there! Thank you so much for your help.